# Setting type "password" inputs with value from previous submit after validation failure

Tags: php, validation, password-protection

I'm creating a walkup create account page for our website. I've always cleared out the default value="" for a type="password" input out of paranoia, after a user has submitted a form, even if the two passwords match and are valid. I started to think on this after our designer asked me if there was any real point to doing that. I can certainly echo the passwords into the value="" field after submit, if they are not the offending validation failure, but are there vulnerabilities associated with this approach? We're defaulting to https on this particular page. I know that you could do an html rewrite to change the input type such that you are echo'ing into a non-masked input, but that seems like it could only affect the user locally.

Example form:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>">
<input type="password" name="password1" value="">
<input type="password" name="password2" value="">
```

On submit, check if the username looks like a proper email, the passwords match, and the passwords beat our minimal requirements. If the email offends, but the passwords don't, could I add...

```
<input type="password" name="password1" value="<?php echo $password1; ?>">
<input type="password" name="password2" value="<?php echo $password2; ?>">
```

... and be worry free? And no, I'm not using register globals. I pull them out of $_POST manually and do sanitization first.

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should not do it as a colleague could steal your password going to the profile page and do a view source.

You probably should not be able to implement this functionality if your passwords are scrambled using a [secure hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA_hash_functions) as that is a single way and you are unable to get the original password back.

Comment: I use a sha1 + salt, once the password is actually validated. So, the main deterrent is physical access to the computer WHILE someone is specifically on this create account page?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a bad idea to do it this way because the HTML source may be cached, even when you tell it using HTTP headers that it should not be cached. This is dependant upon the browsers, and Microsoft suggests including an additional HEAD tag after the BODY tag. [Microsoft has more information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/222064) on this "feature" for Internet Explorer.